# jQuery clearInterval on slideToggle

Tags: jquery, hover, setinterval, slidetoggle, clearinterval

I have a div that when hovered over, slideToggles a `<p>` tag to become visible and then I activate a setInterval to animate the visible `<p>` tag, when the user no longer hovers on the div the `<p>` tags becomes hidden like it should but the animation still continues to run. I have tried everything I can think of to stop the animation when you users no longer hovers, but I am new to jQuery and I have been unsuccessful.

Here is the fiddle to show you what I have, http://jsfiddle.net/Yokocapolo/g7AyV/

I would like the `<p>` tag to go back the start when it is no longer being hovered over and for the animation to start again when the user hovers back on the div.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Your question inspired me for my website! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work by adding the `span` on hover and then removing it on `mouseleave`.

I stored the `span` and the text node as a variable then using the `append()` I appended it to the `p` tag. When the user moved off I used `remove()` to remove the variable on `mouseleave`.

To see it working click the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Yokocapolo/g7AyV/7/

Thanks again to those who answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

Add this event at the end of your script:

```
$('#portRibbon').mouseout(function(){
    $('#text3').animate({duration:0});
});
```

Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/saidbakr/g7AyV/1/

From [Jquery Api](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> **Additional Notes:**
>
> *All jQuery effects, including .animate(), can be
> turned off globally by setting jQuery.fx.off = true, which effectively
> sets the duration to 0. For more information, see jQuery.fx.off.*

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I had a look at your fiddle and the animation was still running and the fx.off did not stop it each, however I have just spent several hours fixing it and I now have it working. None of your answer went to waste though, as I needed to incorporate it and change it slightly. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an interval set to zero to run an animation?

The animation will run thousands of times every second screwing up your browser, and there should'nt be any need for interval function at all, but it should probably be more like this:

```
var timer;

$('#portRibbon').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $('#text3').stop(true,true).css('top', '0px');
        $('#portDescription').slideDown(500, function() {
            $('#text3').animate({
                'top': '-35px'
            }, 6000).delay(1000).animate({
                'top': '0px'
            });
        });
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $('#portDescription').slideUp(500);
    }
});
```

​[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/g7AyV/2/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I wanted the description to repeat like a billboard, that way someone could get another chance to read it if they missed it, I have also managed to fix it myself in the end, thanks again for the help.